# Python check if function exists without running it

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, try-catch

In python how do you check if a function exists without actually running the function (i.e. using try)? I would be testing if it exists in a module.

Comment: Depend on the context, if is a class, if is global defined, you-ll have to extend the question to provide more elements.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#dir) to check if a name is in a module:

```
>>> import os
>>> "walk" in dir(os)
True
>>>
```

In the sample code above, we test for the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) function.

Comment: And then to see if it's actually a function, `callable(getattr(os,'walk'))`

Comment: What if I want to know if it exists at a global namespace (or from existing imports)?

Comment: Use callable(getattr(os,'walk', None)) if you don't want to throw an exception

Answer (score 30):

You suggested `try` `except`. You could indeed use that:

```
try:
    variable
except NameError:
    print("Not in scope!")
else:
    print("In scope!")
```

This checks if `variable` is in scope (it doesn't call the function).

Comment: They specifically said without running the function and gave try as an example of what they don't want to do.

Comment: @fun4jimmy This doesn't call the function - that would require `variable()`. It just checks if `variable` is defined.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise you could do that. I don't seem to be able to remove the downvote unless you edit your answer. Can you change something minor so I can remove it?

Answer (score 17):

```
Solution1:
import inspect
if (hasattr(m, 'f') and inspect.isfunction(m.f))

Solution2:
import inspect
if ('f' in dir(m) and inspect.isfunction(m.f))
```

where:
m = module name
f = function defined in m

Answer (score 4):

If you are checking if function exists in a package:

```
import pkg

print("method" in dir(pkg))
```

If you are checking if function exists in your script / namespace:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")

print("hello" in dir())
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking for a function in your code, use global()

```
if "function" in globals():
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my solution here. It's 8 years late, and similar variant been suggested, but here is more capable version.
Just for those, who find this as i did.

```
def check(fn):
    def c():pass
    for item in globals().keys():
        if type(globals()[item]) == type(c) and fn == item:
            return print(item, "is Function!")
        elif fn == item:
            return print(fn, "is", type(globals()[item]))
    return print("Can't find", fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the function in class, you can use a "__dict__" option. E.g to check if the function "some_function" in "some_class" do:

```
if "some_function" in list(some_class.__dict__.keys()):
    print('Function {} found'.format ("some_function"))
```

Comment: You should just use `hasattr(some_class, "some_function")` for more clarity and because sometimes __dict__ is not used, although this still does not check whether you’re dealing with a function or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this work also and look simpler for me:

```
def newFunc():
    print("hello")

if newFunc:
    print("newFunc function is exist")
else:
    print("newFunc function is not exist")
```