# How to check if function exists without running it in Julia?

Tags: julia

Just want to find an analogue of this answer:
[Python check if function exists without running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926909/python-check-if-function-exists-without-running-it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check with `isdefined`.

```
isdefined(ModuleName, :function_name)
```

Example:

```
using Statistics

julia> isdefined(Statistics, :std)
true

julia> isdefined(Base, :std)
false
```

Comment: If one is looking for functions defined at the REPL, then `isdefined(Main, :foo)`.

Answer (score 4):

To make sure it is a function, Julia allows you to check its type too:

```
julia> isdefined(Main, :sin)
true

julia> isdefined(Main, :Int)
true

julia> isdefined(Main, :sin) && getproperty(Main, :sin) isa Function
true

julia> isdefined(Main, :Int) && getproperty(Main, :Int) isa Function
false

julia> import Dates

julia> isdefined(Dates, :month) && getproperty(Dates, :month) isa Function
true
```

---

Relatedly, once you know something is a function,  you can also check whether it applies to a particular set of argument types.

This is important in Julia, as a given function can have several methods implementing it for different sets of argument types. `hasmethod` allows you to make sure that the function applies to your particular set of argument types.

```
julia> hasmethod(+, Tuple{Int, Float64})
true

julia> hasmethod(+, Tuple{Int, String})
false

julia> #can check keyword arguments too
       hasmethod(range, Tuple{Int}, (:stop, :step))
true
```